# Validation not realtime in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i want to make prefix validation on my site, I have been looking for and get what I want, but the problem is, when I was type a value in the input form does not issue notice an error or not, when I click in any place that focus is not in the input field error notice to appear. I want when I am typing in the input field and it appears immediately notice one of them without having to click anywhere in advance. if anyone could help me?

Here's my part of validation code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jkeyboard').blur(function(e) {
    if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Prefix Valid</b>');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Wrong Prefix</b>');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});

function validatePhone(jkeyboard) {
  var a = document.getElementById(jkeyboard).value;
  var filter = /^0(?:8(?:(?:1(?:[789][0-9]{0,8})?|3(?:[1238][0-9]{0,8})?|5(?:9[0-9]{0,8})?|7(?:[78][0-9]{0,8})?)?)?)?$/;
  //var filter = /^0([8]([1357]([123789]([0-9]{0,8}))?)?)?$/;
  if (filter.test(a)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` event

```
$('#jkeyboard').on('input', function(e) {
    if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Prefix Valid</b>');
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Wrong Prefix</b>');
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#jkeyboard').on('input', function(e) {
    if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Prefix Valid</b>');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Wrong Prefix</b>');
      $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});

function validatePhone(jkeyboard) {
  var a = document.getElementById(jkeyboard).value;
  var filter = /^0(?:8(?:(?:1(?:[789][0-9]{0,8})?|3(?:[1238][0-9]{0,8})?|5(?:9[0-9]{0,8})?|7(?:[78][0-9]{0,8})?)?)?)?$/;
  //var filter = /^0([8]([1357]([123789]([0-9]{0,8}))?)?)?$/;
  if (filter.test(a)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="jkeyboard" />
<div id="spnPhoneStatus"></div>
```

Comment: my input fields have been integrated with the virtual keyboard is made of jquery (mottie keyboard), it's work if type manually when using the virtual keyboard it's doesn't work

Comment: @Eightleven i see an event 'keyboardChange' on their documentation

Comment: how? can you explain me?

Answer (score 0):

Use **keyup** or **change** event

```
$('#jkeyboard').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Prefix Valid</b>');
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
    } else {
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Wrong Prefix</b>');
        $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#jkeyboard').on('change', function(e) {
        if (validatePhone('jkeyboard')) {
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Prefix Valid</b>');
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').html('<b>Wrong Prefix</b>');
            $('#spnPhoneStatus').css('color', 'red');
        }
    });
```

Comment: my input fields have been integrated with the virtual keyboard is made of jquery (mottie keyboard), it's work if type manually when using the virtual keyboard it's doesn't work